# Best initial - final position associations problem in c++ with branch and bound algorithm

Tags: c++, optimization, branch-and-bound

I'm working on a game prototype. I need to associate `N` starting positions to `N` ending positions while minimizing the sum of each distance.

I'm currently on a 2D projet, but this problem also applies to 3D (or higher dimension).

In university, I learned an algorithm that do more or less that. It's called Branch and Bound ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound)).

The algorithm is perfect in term of giving the good result. I was skeptical at first, but it works. But, my implementation is to slow for realtime usage. For a `N` of 10, the algorithm take about 8 to 10 seconds to perform. I don't know why it is that slow and I want to optimise it.

Here is my test implementation in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <queue>
#include <tuple>
#include <cmath>

const float Epsilon = 0.0005f;

class HashMap {
private:
    size_t* map;
    size_t size;

public:
    explicit HashMap(size_t size) {
        this->size = size;
        map = new size_t[size];
        for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            map[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    ~HashMap() {
        delete map;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            map[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    void insert(size_t key, size_t value) {
        map[key] = value;
    }

    size_t get(size_t key) {
        return map[key];
    }

    void remove(size_t key) {
        map[key] = -1;
    }
};

struct Vector2 {
    float x, y; // Assuming a 2D vector
};

float distance(const Vector2& v1, const Vector2& v2) {
    float dx = v1.x - v2.x;
    float dy = v1.y - v2.y;
    return std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

float getBestLineSolution(HashMap& usedValues, size_t size, const float* distances, size_t line) {
    auto best = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (usedValues.get(i) == -1 && distances[line * size + i] < best) {
            best = distances[line * size + i];
        }
    }
    return best;
}

float getRemainingScore(HashMap& usedValues, size_t size, const float* distances, size_t line) {
    auto remainingScore = 0.0f;
    for (auto i = line; i < size; i++) {
        remainingScore += getBestLineSolution(usedValues, size, distances, i);
    }
    return remainingScore;
}

float getTotalHeuristic(std::tuple<float, float, std::vector<size_t>> a) {
    // 0 is the true weight up until now and 1 is the heuristics
    return std::get<0>(a) + std::get<1>(a);
}

struct CustomCompare {
    bool operator()(std::tuple<float, float, std::vector<size_t>> a, std::tuple<float, float, std::vector<size_t>> b) {
        // Sort by cost
        return getTotalHeuristic(std::move(a)) > getTotalHeuristic(std::move(b));
    }
};

std::vector<size_t> branchAndBoundIterative(const std::vector<Vector2>& currentPosition, std::vector<Vector2>& finalPositions) {
    auto size = currentPosition.size();
    auto usedPosition = HashMap(size);
    float distances[size * size];
    auto minHeap = std::priority_queue<std::tuple<float, float, std::vector<size_t>>,
                                        std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, std::vector<size_t>>>, CustomCompare>();

    // Initialize the matrix with the distances
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            distances[i * size + j] = distance(currentPosition[i], finalPositions[j]);
        }
    }

    // Getting the threshold
    auto threshold = 0.0f;
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        threshold += distances[i * size + i];
    }

    // Getting all first node whose cost is under the threshold
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        auto dist = distances[i];
        auto heuristic = getRemainingScore(usedPosition, size, distances, 1);

        if (dist + heuristic <= (threshold + Epsilon)) {
            auto v = std::vector<size_t>();
            v.push_back(i);
            minHeap.emplace(dist, heuristic, v);
        }
    }

    // Doing the algorithm
    // This is part is really slow
    auto bestTuple = minHeap.top();
    do {
        // Lower cost path (called current path in the rest of the algorithm)
        auto currentTuple = minHeap.top();
        minHeap.pop();
        usedPosition.clear();
        auto positions = std::get<2>(currentTuple);
        auto posSize = positions.size();

        if (posSize == size) {
            // If the current path (in the matrix) contains all elements
            auto totalDistance = std::get<0>(currentTuple);
            if (totalDistance <= (threshold + Epsilon)) {
                threshold = totalDistance;
                bestTuple = currentTuple;
            }
        } else {
            // If the current path (in the matrix) doesn't contain all elements
            for (auto i = 0; i < posSize; i++) {
                usedPosition.insert(positions[i], i);
            }

            auto currentDist = std::get<0>(currentTuple);

            // Getting the next best result for the next line in the current path
            for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (usedPosition.get(i) == -1) {
                    auto newDist = currentDist + distances[posSize * size + i];
                    auto heuristic = getRemainingScore(usedPosition, size, distances, posSize + 1);
                    if (newDist + heuristic <= (threshold + Epsilon)) {
                        auto positionCopy = std::vector<size_t>(positions);
                        positionCopy.push_back(i);
                        minHeap.emplace(newDist, heuristic, positionCopy);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!minHeap.empty() && getTotalHeuristic(minHeap.top()) <= (threshold + Epsilon));

    return std::get<2>(bestTuple);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Vector2> currentPosition = { {0, 0},
                                             {1, 0},
                                             {2, 0},
                                             {3, 0},
                                             {4, 0},
                                             {5, 0},
                                             {6, 0},
                                             {7, 0},
                                             {8, 0},
                                             {9, 0}
    };

    std::vector<Vector2> finalPosition = { {-4, 5},
                                           {-3, 5},
                                           {-2, 5},
                                           {-1, 5},
                                           {0, 5},
                                           {1, 5},
                                           {2, 5},
                                           {3, 5},
                                           {4, 5},
                                           {5, 5}
    };
    std::vector<size_t> bestFinalPosition = branchAndBoundIterative(currentPosition, finalPosition);

    // Output the result
    std::cout << "Optimal final positions:" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < currentPosition.size(); i++) {
        auto pos = finalPosition[bestFinalPosition[i]];
        std::cout << "(" << pos.x << ", " << pos.y << ") ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The core algorithm is implemented in the branchAndBoundIterative function.
From what I've been able to test, the do while loop seems to be the bottleneck of the algorithm.

The "true" output is the following
Optimal final positions:
(-4, 5) (-3, 5) (-2, 5) (-1, 5) (0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 5) (3, 5) (4, 5) (5, 5)

Comment: Each iteration has a complexity of `O(n^3)` which seems pretty big. Can't you reduce that by iterating over the `distance` array less frequently or use another data structure to avoid iterating over the whole array (like a priority-queue, a tree or something like this)? Alternatively, if the complexity cannot be reduced (unlikely), you can make the code more SIMD-friendly, and avoid iterating on the whole hash-map in `getBestLineSolution` many times from `getRemainingScore`.

Comment: It looks like your call to `getRemainingScore(usedPosition, size, distances, posSize + 1)` is done `size` times for no reason since the arguments appears to be always the same. Calling it once would reduce the complexity to `O(n²)` which is still not great but much better.

Comment: By the way, If you can, consider using `uint32_t` values for your map rather than `size_t` if you know that all values are smaller than 4.2e9. You can even use `uint16_t` if the values are smaller than 6.4e4. Smaller integers takes less space in CPU cache and the RAM so they are faster to fetch. The smaller the better.

Comment: Note that in modern C++ it is generally a bad idea to allocate data manually. Here, the hashmap does not have a user-defined copy or move constructor. Thus, both will cause bugs in your code if they are called. You should use a `std::vector<size_t>` which is safer (or possibly `std::unique<size_t[]>` though you need to still write a copy constructor with this one). A `std::vector` is useful here since it can initialize all the values to `-1` by just calling its constructor properly.

Comment: Note that `size_t` is generally *unsigned*. This means you cannot initialize the value of your map with `-1` value (unsigned values cannot contain negative numbers). `-1` will be translated to `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()-1` in practice due to the implicit cast to `size_t`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I reread my implementation and I don't need the values inside the hashmap, I only need to know if a certain index is used. So I used a vector<bool> instead of a vector<size_t> (like you said, size_t cause problems with negative values, I forgot that part when implementing the algorithm).